# Heaven scored big time

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Hi what could this sentence means?

> While heaven scored big time, Charly we will meet you again somewhere over the rainbow.

Comment: Please be sure to include more details in your posts, like the source of the quote, the surrounding context, and your own research. Otherwise, your post might be closed. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like out of an informal obituary.

It means that Charly died and was a very great person.  Consequently heaven (where good people are supposed to go) gained a lot, it "scored big time".  "We will meet you again somewhere over the rainbow" indicates that the person is missed to a degree that those expressing the sentiment look forward to at one time joining their company in the afterlife.